# How to stub CXF endpoint in Camel Blueprint

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel, cxf, blueprint-osgi

I need to write some unit tests for Camel routes that use CXF component to call a SOAP web service.
**What would be the cleanest way to skip the SOAP request and return a stubbed response?**
I'm trying with mock endpoints but the request is either passed to the real endpoint or ignored in `whenAnyExchangeReceived` processor callback.

I'm configuring Camel with Blueprint and running it with camel-test-blueprint 2.17.1. This is how my blueprint.xml configuration looks like.

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
        xmlns:camelcxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <cm:property-placeholder id="routeConfiguration"
        persistent-id="my.app" />

    <camelcxf:cxfEndpoint id="myWebService"
                  address="${myWebService.url}"
                  wsdlURL="classpath:wsdl/MyWebService.wsdl"
                  serviceClass="my.web.service.Ws"
                  serviceName="s:MyWebServiceImpl"
                  xmlns:s="http://mywebservice.it/"/>


    <camelContext trace="false" id="myCamelContext"
                  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <propertyPlaceholder location="blueprint:routeConfiguration" />

        <route id="IwantToStubInsideHere">
            <from uri="activemq:someQueue"/>
            <to uri="cxf:bean:myWebService"/>
            <to uri="direct:processWebServiceResponse"/>
        </route>

    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Test class

```
public class RouteTest extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {
    @Override
    public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
        return "cxf*";
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:cxf:bean:myWebService");
        mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockEndpoint.whenAnyExchangeReceived(new StubWsProcessor());
        // run route here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem we're facing. For the moment we did not see any other alternative to create a fake server (like with SOAP-UI) but we did not go this way. For the  moment we make integration testing only for this case with the real WS.

Comment: @ruffp I posted my actual setup. Works pretty well for my case, hope you can adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my solution. I totally removed CXF bean from my route and replaced its endpoint with a property. During tests the property value is changed to an appropriate endpoint e.g. `direct:something`.
My setup is a bit more complicate as it involves dynamic routers but here's the gist of it:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="routeConfiguration"
                         persistent-id="my.app">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="cxfEndpoint" value="cxf:bean:myWebService"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
.....
<route id="IwantToStubInsideHere">
    <from uri="activemq:someQueue"/>
    <to uri="${cxfEndpoint}"/>
    <to uri="direct:processWebServiceResponse"/>
</route>
```

Default value is ok for production use, and it is overridden only during testing by defining `cxfEndpoint` inside the appropriate *my.app.cfg* file.